# FrobeniusSolve: how does it work?

Tags: number-theory, implementation-details

Can someone suggest any reference to read? I would like to understand how the algorithm works.

Comment: Here is Wolfram's official answer to your question: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WhyYouDoNotUsuallyNeedToKnowAboutInternals.html

Comment: You can try `Trace[FrobeniusSolve[list, 5], TraceInternal -> True] >> "frob.txt"` and then [this](http://pastebin.com/HMpptJV9) is the result.  So, how MMA does it, may be tricky to find out.  But the two papers in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/67169/210969) give methods for solving these problems

Comment: There's a decent chance that the method is related to the one described [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=vntDnyh0gacC&lpg=PA509&ots=iOWQ_o6rUc&dq=LinearDiophantineSolve&pg=PA507#v=onepage&q=frobenius&f=false) by Michael Trott for solving linear Diophantine equations

Comment: It uses integer linear programming. Relevant details to underlying method are described in a paper you can access [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221333744_Making_Change_and_Finding_Repfigits_Balancing_a_Knapsack).

Comment: Thank you Daniel. You introduced me some months ago to "Grobner basis" and apparently this is another example of this mathematical wonder!

Comment: No, we don't use GB for `FrobeniusSolve`. Can be done that way but not so efficiently (although specialized toric GB code, e.g. as in the program 4t2, does a good job of it).